Makefile: Include gives "No such file or directory" although file exists
I am trying to include another Makefile ("Makefile2") in the same folder into a Makefile like this:
OTHER_MAKEFILE_PATH = ./Makefile2

.PHONY: build
build:
    @test -e $(abspath $(OTHER_MAKEFILE_PATH)) && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exists"
    -include $(abspath ./Makefile2)

The console output is
❯ make build
File exists
include /Users/xxx/yyy/test/Makefile2
make: include: No such file or directory
make: [build] Error 1 (ignored)

I don't get why the include gives a file-not-found error? Anybody got an idea?
I am using GNU Make 3.81 on macOS 14.5 with M2 chip.
I tried it with absolute and relative paths, neither worked.
I expect that when the file exists the other makefile is included (at least not giving an error if there is nothing to do for it).

It doesn't say that the Makefile2 is not found, it says that include is not found. Everything indented with a tab is a shell command (except for $(...) substitutions in it), while include is not a shell command, it's a makefile directive. It has to be outside of the recipe.

As HolyBlackCat figured out, it's because the include directive needs to be outside of the recipe section.
